# how to config the home page locally

Tags: apache, localhost

I am new to wordpress and apache. Following the introduction i found from google, i installed the apache(2.2.17)+mysql(5.5.11)+php(5.2.17)+wordpress(3.1.1) successfully on my PC. But when I login with the right user name and password, it just go into the wp-admin directory but not the homepage.

I guess I missed some configurations of the apache server or something else.

Could anyone can help on this, or give a link.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your home page is available on the link in the upper left corner right besides the WordPress logo.

#### Update

In your [.htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) or **httpd-vhosts.conf** you have to declare the index.php as index file, and FollowSymLinks has to be On:

```
# sample .htaccess code
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: yeah. I means when i input http://localhost/index.php it just show the directory of the document root but not the home page.

Comment: @Dyun Add this information to your question. I made an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress setup takes you to the admin panel at the start. Once you are done configuring your setup, simply type in the address of your setup in the browser's address bar.

For example, if I have setup wp in "blog" directory, then the admin panel login is at http://mysite.com/blog/wp-admin and the blog can be viewed at http://mysite.com/blog